# switch (unknown variable type)

Tags: java, switch-statement, owl-api

I want to do some treatments depending on `superClassII` type. So, I defined :

```
ClassExpressionType superClassIIType = superClassII.getClassExpressionType();
```

If (superClassIIType  = "ObjectMincardinality"`or`"ObjectExactCardinality"`so,

```
I do the same treatment for superClassII
```

`else` we do nothing.

Here is a part of my source code:

```
switch(superClassIIType){
    case OBJECT_EXACT_CARDINALITY:
    case OBJECT_MIN_CARDINALITY:
        if ((((superClassIIType)superClassII).getProperty().equals(
            ((OWLObjectMinCardinality)superClass).getProperty() ){

            int superClassIICardinality =((superClassIIType)superClassII).getCardinality();
            ...
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

But, it seems that `superClassIIType` is not accepted. I tried to do what I need by a simple `if ...else` where there the if and else blocks contain both the same treatment(it works but I think it is naive).

Could you please tell me where is the problem and if implement what I need using another alternative))

Comment: This is more like a Java problem than it has anything to do with OWL. `superClassIIType` is an object, not a java class, You cannot cast to it. The associated interfaces are [`OWLObjectExactCardinality`](http://owlcs.github.io/owlapi/apidocs_4/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLObjectExactCardinality.html) and [`OWLObjectMinCardinality`](http://owlcs.github.io/owlapi/apidocs_4/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLObjectMinCardinality.html).

Comment: ... but you can probably get away with casting to [`OWLObjectCardinalityRestriction`](http://owlcs.github.io/owlapi/apidocs_4/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLObjectCardinalityRestriction.html) in your case, which has the desired methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is best done with a visitor, although it will require you to duplicate the code. If you are using OWLAPI 5, implement `OWLClassExpressionVisitor` - here are default methods for everything so you'll have to implement just the two methods for the types you wish to use.

```
    OWLClassExpressionVisitor visitor = new OWLClassExpressionVisitor() {
        public void visit(OWLObjectMinCardinality c) {
            int superClassIICardinality = c.getCardinality();
        }

        @Override
        public void visit(OWLObjectExactCardinality ce) {
            int superClassIICardinality = c.getCardinality();
        }
    };
    superClassII.accept(visitor);
```